# GROUP_CONCAT show individual columns in PHP

Tags: php, sql, mysqli

How do I show individual columns in php with GROUP_CONCAT?

In my code below, I am using GROUP_CONCAT to group "start_date", "title", and "location" all into "data". I want to define each of these as php variables, rather than just "data". Is this possible?

```
function events_calendar() {
 global $connection;
 mysqli_select_db($connection);
 $query = ("SELECT month, GROUP_CONCAT(start_date, title, location) as data FROM events GROUP BY month");
 $result = $connection->query($query);
 $str = "";
 while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
     $data = $row['data'];
     $str .= $data
 }
 return $str;
}
```

My issue with using multiple GROUP_CONCATs for each column is that my data doesn't come out properly. I want it to come out like this so that the appropriate data is categorized under each month group:

```
month: start_date 1, location 1, title 1    start_date 2, location 2, title 2
next month: start_date 3, location 3, title 3
next month: start_date 4, location 4, title 4
```

NOT like this:

```
month: start_date 1, start_date 2   location 1, location 2   title 1, title 2
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to put a separator between the columns, and make it different from the separator between the rows in the group:

```
GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT_WS(', ', start_date, location, title) SEPARATOR '\t') AS data
```

This will put comma between each column, and TAB between each row's data.

Then in PHP you can use `$data = explode('\t', $row['data'])` to get an array of each row's data, and `explode(', ', $data[$i])` to get each column within it.

Comment: Thanks, I tried this, but the first variable: $data = explode('\t', $row['data'])  returns just the word "Array", and the second variable I set: $title = explode(':', $data[1]) causes the page to crash. Why is this happening?

Comment: `$data` is an array, if you want to see what it contains use `var_dump()`, not `echo`.

Comment: Sorry, `:` should have been `,`.